# 2013 Template builder error (SoapException - security level)

Tags: 2013, template-builder

I am using the SDL Template Builder 7.1 (build 7.1.0.114).

The template builder worked correctly for a long time but now I am getting the following error by every template I try to debug:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Type
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef and the types derived from it (such as
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef) are not permitted to be deserialized
>   at this security level.
>
> at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.Proxy.CompoundTemplateWebService.StartDebuggingWithItemUri(String
>   compoundTemplateId, String compoundTemplateXml, String itemId, Boolean
>   includeSystemLog, TraceEventType logLevel)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.DebugObject.Start(Template
>   template, Object debugItem, LoggingOptions loggingOptions)

In the Event Viewer I see the following error:

```
Type System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef and the types derived from it (such as System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef) are not permitted to be deserialized at this security level. Component: CompoundTemplateWebService Errorcode: 0 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE StackTrace Information Details: Server stack trace: at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.CheckTypeSecurity(Type t, TypeFilterLevel securityLevel) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ParseObject(ParseRecord pr) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run() at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.DeserializeBinaryRequestMessage(String objectUri, Stream inputStream, Boolean bStrictBinding, TypeFilterLevel securityLevel) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryServerFormatterSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream) Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebuggerRemoteRunner.Ping() at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.Debugger.GetRemoteDebugger(String userName, String webServiceDirectory) at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.Debugger.StartNewDebugger(String compoundTemplateUri, String compoundTemplateContent, String itemUri, String packageContents, Boolean preview, String publicationTargetUri, String userName, Boolean logTridionClasses, TraceEventType logLevel) at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.Debugger.StartNewDebuggerForItemUri(String compoundTemplateUri, String compoundTemplateContent, String itemUri, Boolean preview, String publicationTargetUri, String userName, Boolean logTridionClasses, TraceEventType logLevel) at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.WebService.CompoundTemplateWebService.StartDebuggingWithItemUri(String compoundTemplateId, String compoundTemplateXml, String itemId, Boolean includeSystemLog, TraceEventType logLevel)
```

**What I already tried:**

- I tried the 'Log on As...' option but that didn't help.
- I checked some other Stack Exchange posts but couldn't find the same situation.
- I added the following section to the web.config in Tridion/templating directory (after a suggestion from Nuno)

[image: template builder web.config]

Update 06-02-2016
- I also added the `typeFilterLevel=Full` setting to the  TcmTemplateBuilder.exe.config

I am really convinced that is has to do with the TypeFilter setting because the following line in the event viewer:

*System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.CheckTypeSecurity(Type t, TypeFilterLevel securityLevel)*

Thanks in advance!

**update: ticket is @SDL R+D team right now**

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268105/net-remoting-passing-objects-into-methods), you are "probably running your application in a trust-level that is too low."

Googling for "application trust level" will probably give you some tips. You could also try opening the CME in Internet Explorer and tweaking the zone for that website to "Intranet" or something like that? It uses the same URL as the Template Builder, so it might be enough.

Comment: Hi Nuno, thank you for your comment. I tried the IE trick but that didn't work.

The suggestion about the 'typeFilterLevel' looks promising. In which web.config should I add the following code?

 <channels>
         <channel ref=”http”>
            <serverProviders>            
               <provider ref=”wsdl” />
               <formatter ref=”soap” typeFilterLevel=”Full” />
            </serverProviders>
         </channel>
      </channels>

Is that the web.config in the templating directory?

Comment: That would be my guess too.

Comment: I also updated the TcmTemplateBuilder.exe.config (because that is the client config) but still no success. I also added the Event Viewer error to my question which confirms it has to do with the TypeFilterLevel... I will raise a ticket and let you know the result.